# Custom sorting of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a binomail dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:200,1000,rep=TRUE)))
addme <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df <- cbind(df,addme)
df <-df[order(df$replicate.1..sample.0.1..1000..rep...TRUE..),]
```

The data is currently soreted in a way to show the instances belonging to 0 group then the ones belonging to the 1 group. Is there a way I can sort the data in a 0-1-0-1-0... fashion? I mean to show a row that belongs to the 0 group, the row after belonging to the 1 group then the zero group and so on...

All I can think about is complex functions. I hope there's a simple way around it.

Thank you,

Comment: First of all, I assume your variable is not meant to be named the way it is? Secondly, what criteria will determine the order after the 0-1-0 arrangement?

Comment: @RichardScriven - I guess that depends on the `sample()`...

Comment: @alexwhan Yes, you're right it does.  Which is even more annoying than the column name.  This question needs clarification for cases where there are more 1's than 0's or vice versa, and the sample data should be a bit smaller.  And `X5` can be the column name in `addme`

Comment: 1000 rows aren't really needed are they? `set.seed(2);
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:200,10,rep=TRUE)), addme=sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE))` would be more than sufficient.

Comment: @RichardScriven - agreed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt, which will add any extra 1's at the end:

First make some example data:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:200,10,rep=TRUE)),
                              addme=sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE))
```

Then order:

```
with(df, df[unique(as.vector(rbind(which(addme==0),which(addme==1)))),])

#    X1  X2  X3  X4 addme
#2  141  48  78  33     0
#1   37 111 133   3     1
#3  115 153 168 163     0
#5  189  82  70 103     1
#4   34  37  31 174     0
#6  189 171  98 126     1
#8  167  46  72  57     0
#7   26 196  30 169     1
#9   94  89 193 134     1
#10 110  15  27  31     1
#Warning message:
#In rbind(which(addme == 0), which(addme == 1)) :
#  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using `dplyr`, which would make it suitable for within-group ordering. It's also probably pretty quick. If there's unbalanced numbers of 0's and 1's, it will leave them at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    arrange(addme) %>%
    mutate(n0 = sum(addme == 0),
           orderme = seq_along(addme) - (n0 * addme) + (0.5 * addme)) %>%
    arrange(orderme) %>%
    select(-n0, -orderme)
```